# Is there Maps application on non-3G iPad 2?

Tags: ipad, gps, geolocation, cellular-data

As I know iPad 3G can define user's location using A-GPS module, and there is a Maps application which is closely related to this functionality.

But can non-3G iPads define user's location basing on WiFi routers position, for example? Is there any Maps application?

Comment: http://maps.google.com

Comment: Yes - all of them with downloadable tiles work. (as well as they can based only on WiFi cached tower locations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as is now disclosed in the location database kerfuffle, iOS will cache wifi and cell tower location near it's location so that when internet access is temporarily unavailable, the device can still [trilaterate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration) based on what the WiFi receiver is seeing for SSID.

So, I have had my non 3G iPad correctly locate itself driving down the highway 50 miles from where it last had a WiFi connection. If I have purchased any map product that stores it's own map tiles, it would work. Even the built in map program caches tiles, so I would generate driving directions and step through all the turns to download the map tiles along the way on the device. As long as the device doesn't quit that app / purge those downloaded tiles, the built in map works well for me without 3G data.

Of course, you don't have actual control over downloading a region of tiles or controlling which wifi hotspots are downloaded into the system cache. Also - this means if you are outside the range of any WiFi signal (or the ones that are nearby are not mapped in the database) - your device is clueless at to it's location.

Basically, the hardware limits the ability to use GPS and cellular data and maps are not further handicapped just because a non-3G iPad has less connectivity. Pick the app you like and see how it works in your enviroment. You can always [add external GPS input](http://aviationmentor.blogspot.com/2011/02/gns-5870-bluetooth-gps-for-ipad.html) if you can't sell and re-buy a new iPad for less than the cost of an external receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Just like on iPod touches that are also wifi-only with no GPS, non-3G iPads have the built-in Apple Maps application and use wifi to detect location.